Alfresco Process Services override DbSqlSessionFactory?
I am using  Alfresco Process Services 24.2
Spring version - 6.1.5
I have overridden DbSqlSessionFactory in my custom code using below code
CustomDbSqlSessionFactory
package com.activiti.extension.bean.extension.db;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSessionFactory;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.Session;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.sql.SQLException;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomDbSqlSessionFactory extends DbSqlSessionFactory {

    private final ObjectFactory<CustomDbSqlSession> dbSqlSession;

    @Override
    public Session openSession(CommandContext commandContext) {
        return super.openSession(commandContext);
    }

}

And CustomDbSqlSession
package com.activiti.extension.bean.extension.db;

import org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.Entity;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE;

@Slf4j
@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class CustomDbSqlSession extends DbSqlSession {

    public CustomDbSqlSession(CustomDbSqlSessionFactory dbSqlSessionFactory, CustomEntityCache entityCache) {
        super(dbSqlSessionFactory, entityCache);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    @Override
    public List selectListWithRawParameter(String statement, Object parameter, int firstResult, int maxResults) {
        return super.selectListWithRawParameter(statement, parameter, firstResult, maxResults);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    @Override
    public List selectListWithRawParameterWithoutFilter(String statement, Object parameter, int firstResult, int maxResults) {
       return super.selectListWithRawParameterWithoutFilter(statement, parameter, firstResult, maxResults);

    }

    @Override
    protected void flushRegularInsert(Entity persistentObject, Class<? extends Entity> clazz) {
        super.flushRegularInsert(persistentObject, clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected void flushBulkInsert(Collection<Entity> persistentObjectList, Class<? extends Entity> clazz) {
        super.flushBulkInsert(persistentObjectList, clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected void flushUpdates() {
        super.flushUpdates();
    }
}

I am able to compile and create build, After deploying changes to APS I am able to create and execute process .
But in CustomDbSqlSession class, I have overridden few DbSqlSession's methods and that are not getting executed.
I tried by adding logs and debuggers in Intellij Idea it seems flow is not executing in custom overridden method, it's calling the default DbSqlSession's method.
I wanted to execute the CustomDbSqlSession's overridden methods.
Can anyone please help here?

I fixed it using
CustomDbSqlSessionFactory class
package com.activiti.extension.bean.extension.db;

import com.activiti.extension.bean.service.encryption.VariableEncryptionService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSessionFactory;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.Session;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomDbSqlSessionFactory extends DbSqlSessionFactory {

    private final VariableEncryptionService variableEncryptionService;

    @Override
    public Session openSession(CommandContext commandContext) {
       return new CustomDbSqlSession(this, commandContext, variableEncryptionService);
    }

}

Custom CustomDbSqlSession class
package com.activiti.extension.bean.extension.db;

import com.activiti.extension.bean.service.encryption.VariableEncryptionService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException;
import org.activiti.engine.ActivitiOptimisticLockingException;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.db.HasRevision;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.Entity;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE;

@Slf4j
//@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class CustomDbSqlSession extends DbSqlSession {

    private final VariableEncryptionService variableEncryptionService;

    public CustomDbSqlSession(CustomDbSqlSessionFactory dbSqlSessionFactory, CommandContext commandContext,
                              VariableEncryptionService variableEncryptionService) {
        super(dbSqlSessionFactory, commandContext.getEntityCache());
        this.variableEncryptionService = variableEncryptionService;
    }

    private <T> void encrypt(T value) {
        variableEncryptionService.encrypt(value);
    }

    private <T> T decrypt(T value) {
        return variableEncryptionService.decrypt(value);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    @Override
    public List selectListWithRawParameter(String statement, Object parameter, int firstResult, int maxResults) {
        List<Object> result = super.selectListWithRawParameter(statement, parameter, firstResult, maxResults);

        return super.cacheLoadOrStore(result.stream()
                .map(this::decrypt)
                .collect(toList()));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    @Override
    public List selectListWithRawParameterWithoutFilter(String statement, Object parameter, int firstResult, int maxResults) {
        List<Object> result = super.selectListWithRawParameterWithoutFilter(statement, parameter, firstResult, maxResults);
        return result.stream()
                .map(this::decrypt)
                .collect(toList());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    @Override
    public List selectListWithRawParameter(String statement, Object parameter, int firstResult, int maxResults, boolean useCache) {
        List<Object> result = super.selectListWithRawParameter(statement, parameter, firstResult, maxResults, useCache);

        return super.cacheLoadOrStore(result.stream()
                .map(this::decrypt)
                .collect(toList()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void flushRegularInsert(Entity persistentObject, Class<? extends Entity> clazz) {
        encrypt(persistentObject);
        super.flushRegularInsert(persistentObject, clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected void flushBulkInsert(Collection<Entity> persistentObjectList, Class<? extends Entity> clazz) {
        persistentObjectList.forEach(this::encrypt);
        super.flushBulkInsert(persistentObjectList, clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected void flushUpdates() {
        super.updatedObjects.forEach(this::encrypt);
        super.flushUpdates();
      }

}

